# Switch xDB Search indexes from SOLR to Azure Search

Tags: xdb, xconnect, azure-search

I need some assistance switching the xDB search indexes from SOLR to Azure Search in a Sitecore 9 vanilla install (installed using SIF).

I have completed the following tasks:

- Added a Search Service to Azure
- Added the Search Service connection string to xConnect (named collection.search)
- Disabled all SOLR configs in xConnect and enabled all AzureSearch configs
- Restarted the xConnect sites

I was hoping an index would be auto generated as with SOLR but it hasn't and I can't see anything of use in the logs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ensure that *IndexWorker* service is updated in the same way as xConnect site was:

1. Stop *IndexWorker* windows service.
2. Disable all SOLR configs in *IndexWorker* and enable all AzureSearch configs under *search role\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker*
3. Add *collection.search* connection string to *search role\App_data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_config\ConnectionStrings.config*
4. Start *IndexWorker* windows service.

Comment: Can SIF be used to set up xConnect using Azure Search instead of SOLR during the initial install?

Comment: Thanks grg, this appears to be my problem... the IndexWorker isn't running and when I try to start it I get an error.

Comment: To answer the other comments we only want to use Azure Search for the xDB search indexes not for the content search indexes. SIF doesn't provide a way of achieving this.

Comment: @R.Allinson, did you get it working? Or is the indexer still failing to start?

Comment: @Calum, unfortunately it's not possible to setup Azure Search as search provider in OnPrem setup  with SIF out of the box. You might consider writing a custom SIF task for that.
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Installation_Framework/1x/Sitecore_Installation_Framework_12.aspx